# Dynamic parameters with Python's retry decorator

Tags: python, dynamic, python-decorators

I'm currently using the [python retrying package](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/retrying) which contains the `@retry` decorator that has a number of optional parameters. I have these parameters set correctly for our production environment with long enough wait times in between retries (below it's set to 2000 milliseconds) but I would like to set these values differently for unit testing purposes so that execution is very quick.

For example here the wait_fixed time is set to 2000 milliseconds for production but for my unit test that calls `some_function()` I'd like to override the `wait_fixed` parameter to be 1 millisecond so it executes very quickly.

```
@retry(stop_max_attempt_number=3, wait_fixed=2000)
def some_function(self):
    return True
```

The problem I'm running into is that the decorator is [interpreted when the function is defined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2884771/how-to-pass-in-dynamic-data-to-decorators) so as of yet I have not found a way to override the `wait_fixed` parameter from my unit tests.

Comment: Looking at [the source](https://github.com/rholder/retrying/blob/master/retrying.py), there's no easy way to access those parameters via the wrapper object you get back.

Comment: Have you considered having a configuration file for your project? The configuration file can store constants such as these and you can have tailored configuration files for dev / test / prod.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`main.py`

```
import settings
from retrying import retry


@retry(stop_max_attempt_number=settings.STOP_MAX_ATTEMPT_NUMBER, 
       wait_fixed=settings.WAIT_FIXED)
def some_function(self):
    return True
```

`settings.py`

```
import json


with open('config.json') as jsonf:
    config = json.loads(jsonf.read())

WAIT_FIXED=int(config['WAIT_FIXED'])
STOP_MAX_ATTEMPT_NUMBER=int(config['STOP_MAX_ATTEMPT_NUMBER'])
```

`config.json`

```
{
    "STOP_MAX_ATTEMPT_NUMBER" : "3",
    "WAIT_FIXED" : "2000"
}
```

Have your test runner put a suitable `config.json` in place.

Comment: Thanks Horba, I'm currently using Heroku so adding this type of setting to the .env file worked and then I set the default value of wait_fixed to be 2000 ms.

Answer (score 2):

I recently come across a problem which having a `def` inside a `def` resolved the issue.

---

I need to use the retrying decorator on `get_url` function but need to pass configurable value for `stop_max_attempt_number`. There is no way I can come up to have `get_url`, along with other functions at the same indent.

To solve the issue, I have the `get_url` function defined *inside* `get_analytic` function.  For illustration:

```
def get_analytics(conf: Configuration, assets: list, cache: dict) -> list:
    STOP_MAX_ATTEMPT_NUMBER = int(conf.num_retry)
    WAIT_FIXED = int(conf.retry_timeout)
    @retry(stop_max_attempt_number=STOP_MAX_ATTEMPT_NUMBER, wait_fixed=WAIT_FIXED)
    def get_url(disable_https: bool, url: str, user: str, password: str) -> Response:
```

Answer (score 1):

I needed to be able to set the retry parameters dynamically when the function is called, the below worked well for me:

```
import random
from retrying import retry


class MyClass(object):

    def try_stuff(self, string, attempts, wait):
        self.do_something_with_retry = retry(stop_max_attempt_number=attempts,
                                             wait_fixed=wait)(self.do_something_unreliable)
        return self.do_something_with_retry(string)

    def do_something_unreliable(self, string):
        print(string)
        if random.randint(0, 10) > 1:
            raise IOError("Broken sauce, everything is hosed!!!111one")
        else:
            return "Awesome sauce!"

instance = MyClass()

print instance.try_stuff('test', 10, 2000)
```

Answer (score 0):

If not mandatory to use the decorator, use the `retry_call` function from the same retry package

```
def retry_call(f, fargs=None, fkwargs=None, exceptions=Exception, tries=-1, delay=0, max_delay=None, backoff=1,
           jitter=0,
           logger=logging_logger):
```

Refer: https://pypi.org/project/retry/

Better option to handle complex scenario like dynamic calculation of tries & delays based on a fixed timeout value.

For example:

```
timeout = int(os.getenv('TIMEOUT_IN_SECS', 600))
delay = 10
tries = math.ceil(timeout / delay)
result = retry_call(some_function, tries=tries, delay=delay)
```